Corporate space exploration/espionage
I read a novella, around 80-82, about a world run by corporations or possibly guilds, sending 3 separate ships to a world that may have been a Trojan point world. Each ship was very small, only one or maybe just a few highly trained operatives.
They had specific weapons associated with each group, such as the medical specialized group used "venom eggs", grenade like weapons that spread a poison. Another used a coil spring that would wrap around targets immobilizing them, maybe cutting them.
Main character is from neither of these groups but I can't recall his specialty.
I think he ends up in a relationship with a female native.
Might be a YA book.
It was on the new rack in local library as a paperback, so it could have been written anytime earlier than 80s but I don't think it was to much earlier.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you happen to recall the cover art?

A Gift of Mirrorvax by Malcolm MacCloud has weapons called "venom-eggs" and "death-coils," so that seems like a good match.
I haven't read it myself, but it's available to borrow at the Internet Archive.
The book's blurb:

Owned by the planet Vax's largest corporation, Michael is sent on a secret mission to a shadow world, where he is totally unprepared for the adventures awaiting him.


I wonder if he returned to Vax and conquered it with VMS....

A Gift of Mirrorvax! That's the one. I was mid-teens when I read it, 60 now, been bugging me for years and never got an answer from other sites. Thanks!
